# Daño consecutivo en unity C# 2d

Tags: unity, unity2d

Empece a hacer un videojuego en unity hasta ahora tengo este código

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Daño : MonoBehaviour {

    public int daño = 10;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }   


    void OnTriggerEnter2D/*OnCollisionEnter*/(Collider2D collision)
    {
        var hit = collision.gameObject;
        var health = hit.GetComponent<Vida>();
        if (health != null)
        {
            health.TakeDamage(daño);
        }
    }
}
```

Este lo uso para hacerle daño a un personaje que tengo pero solo le hace una vez, ¿Qué hago para que le haga daño hasta que la vida llegue a 0? disculpen si no se explicarme bien.

Comment: Hola veo que quieres hacer un videojuego stackoverflow tiene un foro para eso mira te puede ayudar https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres que le haga daño al personaje mientras estas dentro del collider puedes usar el metodo **OnTriggerStay2D**, de lo contrario si deseas que le haga daño hasta morir al entrar en contacto con el collider, puedes hacer un ciclo:

```
while(health.IsAlive)
{
    health.TakeDamage(damage)
}
```